# python: How to determine which file a dict is from?

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory-leaks, heapy

I'm trying to debug a memory leak.  It's a script that runs as a daemon, and has dependencies in about 10K lines of code in 30 different files.  After a while you see the memory usage start creeping up.

I used heapy to determine that that it's a dict that's growing, but how can I find out which file that dict lives in?

Comment: Do you mean which module's (or modules') namespace has a reference to the `dict`?

Comment: @chepner yes that's correct.